# Spring-Data-JPA Exclude Parameter statement

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-Data-JPA and have a 1:n relationship.

```
    @Entity
    public class MyFirstEntity {
      @Id
      private long id;
      private String paramA;
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="id")
      private MySecondEntity paramB;
      ....

    @Entity
    public class MySecondEntity {
      @Id
      private long id;
      private String paramA;
      @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "paramB")
      @JoinColumn(name="id")
      private Collection<MyFirstEntity> first;
      ....
```

Now I can define the interface with some extra methods like it is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

```
    public interface firstEntityMethods extends CrudRepository<MyFirstEntity, Long> {
      //Example #1
      List<MyFirstEntity> findByParamA (String paramA);
      //Example #2
      List<MyFirstEntity> findByParamAAndParamB (String paramA, MySecondEntity paramB);
      ...
```

Is it possible to declare such a method to exclude an Parameter. Like *findByParamAAndNotByParamB (String paramA, MySecondEntity paramB);*?
So it should find all entities which matches paramA (like example #1) but exclude those which are matching paramB -> (List of Example#1 without List of Example#2).

PS: above code is example code that you can better understand the question. If there are any mistakes/mistypings please ignore them.

Comment: Have you tried it? And have you read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. Are you asking something for example: `findByFirstnameLikeAndFirstnameNotLike`???

Comment: No I search something that I can get a list of MyFirstEntity which have paramA but not paramB.

I found the right syntax, had an mistake at another codepart so firstly it seems that it's not working and I asked this question:
`findByParamAAndParamBNot(String paramA, MySecondEntitty paramB);`is what I need.